# Fitch Formal Proof Question

Tags: proof-explanation, first-order-logic

How would I go about in proving this in Fitch?

$\operatorname{Dodec}(e)$

$\operatorname{Small}(e)$

$\neg\operatorname{Dodec}(e) \lor \operatorname{Dodec}(f) \lor \operatorname{Small}(e)$

Goal: $\operatorname{Dodec}(f).$

I am relatively new to this with no prior experience hence why I am stuck with such question.

With my thinking, I think we would need two subproofs with the conclusion of each being dodec(f) and use disjunction elimination to conclude dodec(f).

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzVXD.png)[This is what I have at the moment]

Comment: Two things: 1. Please check my edits to make sure they are correct. 2. Please show what work you have done so far.

Comment: Okay. I have provided my thinking toward this problem.

Comment: With the current premises of $\ \text{Dodec}(e)\ $,$\ \text{Small}(e)\ $ and $\ \neg\text{Dodec}(e)\vee \text{Dodec}(f)\vee\text{Small}(e)\ $ it's not possible to prove $\ \text{Dodec}(f)\ $, because this could be false while all three premises were true. To get a version of the premises from which $\ \text{Dodec}(f)\ $ could be proved you'll need to change either the second premise to $\ \neg\text{Small}(e)\ $ or the third to $\ \neg\text{Dodec}(e)\vee \text{Dodec}(f)\vee\neg\text{Small}(e)\ $

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in my comment above, the goal $\ \text{Dodec(f)}\ $ is not provable from the premises
\begin{align}
&\text{Dodec(e)}\\
&\text{Small(e)}\ &\text{and}\\
&\neg\text{Dodec(e)}\vee\text{Dodec(f)}\vee\text{Small(e)}\ ,
\end{align}
because if a proposition $\ q\ $ is true, so is the proposition $\ \neg p \vee r\vee q\ $, even if $\ r\ $ is false. Therefore, if $\ p\ $, $\ q\ $ and $\ r\ $ are atomic propositions, then $\ r\ $ cannot be a consequence of $\ p\ $, $\ q\ $ and $\ \neg p \vee r\vee q\ $.

In your attempted proof you have already obtained
$$\ \text{Dodec(e)}\implies\text{Dodec(f)}\ $$
and
$$\ \neg\text{Small(e)}\implies\text{Dodec(f)}\ ,$$
given the premises. You can also easily obtain
 $$\ \text{Dodec(f)}\implies\text{Dodec(f)}\ .$$
Thus, if you were to replace your third premise with $$
\neg\text{Dodec(e)}\vee\text{Dodec(f)}\vee\neg\text{Small(e)}\ ,
$$
you would *then* be able to conclude $\ \text{Dodec(f)}\ $ by disjunction elimination.